# how to query strings with incasesensitive the text in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string

I'm looking for data in two fields with one filed must be the same, one using query

i have data

```
{
"NUMBER" : "5587120",
"SID" : "121213-13131-_X",
"ADDRESS" : "purwakarta"
}
```

i have tried use query string like this

```
GET test/_doc/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {"match" : {"NUMBER" : "5587120"}}
        ],
        "filter" : {
          "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "SID.keyword",
            "query" : "*X*"
          }
        }
    }

  }
```

when I enter the same text as the one recorded, the data I want appears, but when I write the text with lowercase, the data doesn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's not clear from your question, that on which field you want the case insensitive search, based on the context I am assuming its the `SID.keyword` field.

**Why your solution not working**: Please note that [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) fields are not analyzed and indexed in elasticsearch as it is, so **in case of your field `SID.keyword` you are providing its value `121213-13131-_X` so it will be stored as it is, it will not create just one token which is exactly same as the provided value.**

Now you are using the `query_string` on-field `SID.keyword`, hence your [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#CO214-1) will use the same analyzer configured for the field which is the [keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html) which is again no-op analyzer, hence doesn't lowercase the `*X*` provided in the query.

**Solution** : If you want the `insensitive` search than instead of using the `SID.keyword` field, simply creates a custom analyzer which uses the `keyword` analyzer and then passes it to `lowercase` token filter, so your `121213-13131-_X` will be converted to `121213-13131-_x`(Note small case `x`). And then your query string will also use the same analyzer and will match the document **as ultimately elasticsearch works on tokens match**.